# How to call an @injected class

Tags: java, maven

I started working on a `Java` repo (first time I see `Java`) and I'm having a lot of issues with the most trivial things. They use `Maven` and every class uses `@injected`. So, for example, I need to run the `doSomething` method of class `B` inside `A`:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import a_path.B;

@Named
public class A {
    @Inject
    protected B b;

    public void method() {
       b.doSomething();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import a_path.C;


class B {
    @Inject
    protected C c;

    public void doSomething() {
       c.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

So okay, to make some modifications to `doSomething` I create a `main` method to test my changes inside class `A` like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import a_path.B;

@Named
public class A {
    @Inject
    protected B b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a = new A();
       a.b.doSomething();
    }

    public void method() {
       b.doSomething();
    }
}
```

And I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`, I print `b` and is `null`. So what I'm guessing after a lot of headaches is that `@inject` is doing some magic that I need to be aware of to make it work. Basically every `@inject` object is `null` when I try to use them in `main`. My question is what is the correct way of running inside `main` `@injected` objects. Let me know if you need more context, and thanks!

Comment: `new A(..)` will _never_ respect injection annotations.  You _must_ ask the Dependency Injection engine for an instance of A.

Comment: Got it, thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "magic" is called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). The way to get object instances depends on the framework being used (Spring, Guice, Dagger, etc). Look at the maven dependencies to figure out which one is used.

For example if Guice is used than to get A you need to get `Injector` first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(); // may require module(s) for C
  A a = injector.getInstance(A.class);
  a.b.doSomething();
}
```

Equivalent for Spring:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(A.class, B.class, C.class);
  // or AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package of A, B, C");

  A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
  a.b.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Oh, okay, it's spring, but not boot spring. Would u mind to give an equivalence?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'm getting somewhere. I'm selecting this as the accepted answer, however I'm getting an error because if class `C` depends on other `@injected class D` and so on, generates `Failed to introspect bean class [a_path.D] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on`

Comment: @Marcos That is something else.  Open a new question.